# ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\Shreya Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-uoj9me_o

Tags: python, github, pip, librosa

Getting this error while installing **librosa**:

> ERROR: No .egg-info directory found in C:\Users\Shreya Gupta\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-uoj9me_o

I have tried the following things:

1. Upgrading the setup tools: `pip install --upgrade setuptools pip`
2. For installing I have tried the following methods:

- `pip install librosa`
- Using source:

  ```
  tar xzf librosa-VERSION.tar.gz
  cd librosa-VERSION/
  python setup.py install
  ```
- `pip install git+https://github.com/librosa/librosa`

Nothing seems to be working. Getting the same error as above mentioned in all the installation methods.

**Solution that worked** - Using conda "conda install -c conda-forge librosa" to install worked fine.

Comment: I found [this](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/165) GitHub issue with users sharing their solutions, you could try attempting some of the fixes that worked for them.

Comment: try `pip install numpy` before installing `librosa`

Comment: @GodIsOne I tried this as well, doesn't work for me

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal Thank you, I did see this too and tried the steps but it is still not working for me.

Comment: @GodIsOne It's "pip 23.0"

Comment: @GodIsOne I guess this version is not available. Did you mean 21.2.4?

Comment: Using conda "conda install -c conda-forge librosa" to install worked fine